# Something like Spree for Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, spree

Is there something like Spree (Rails) for Grails? I've seen the answers on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543129/grails-ecommerce-framework-platform but it is more than half a year old and didn't give an answer that is similar to Spree.

Comment: Why not just use Spree and share a database with a Grails app?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a new plugin based on Broadleaf Commerce. Wich is an open source Java eCommerce platform based on the Spring Framework...

http://grails.org/plugin/broadleaf

Answer (score 0):

Please check out Greenfield. http://opengreenfield.org/. Built on the Grails framework.